# Gitlab CI pipeline failing: a tag issue

Tags: kubernetes, continuous-integration, yaml, pipe

My gitlab CI pipeline is setup to run maven tests from a docker image created from my maven project.

I have tested the pipeline on my master branch and it worked fine and ran the test.

However I have created a new feature branch and now running the pipeline yet again, however I now get this error

```sh
error checking push permissions -- make sure you entered the correct tag name, and that you are authenticated correctly, and try again: getting tag for destination: repository can only contain the runes `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_-./`: it2901/cs344-maven:feature/produce-allocation-pdf
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1
```

I can't seem to pinpoint the problem at all. I have also pushed the tag: *`tut3`* to the feature branch as well.

Here is my .gitlab-ci.yml: https://controlc.com/7a94a00f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you shared, you have this configured:

```sh
VERSIONLABELMETHOD: "tut3" # options: "","LastVersionTagInGit"
```

It should be either:

```sh
VERSIONLABELMETHOD: ""
```

or

```sh
VERSIONLABELMETHOD: "LastVersionTagInGit"
```

or

```sh
VERSIONLABELMETHOD: "OnlyIfThisCommitHasVersion"
```

When you specify *`"tut3"`*, the script takes it as if it was *`""`* (empty string). Assuming you didn't define `$VERSIONLABEL` anywhere `$ADDITIONALTAGLIST` will also be empty.

And later in the code you can see that this gets executed:

```sh
if [[ "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" == "$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH" ]]; then ADDITIONALTAGLIST="$ADDITIONALTAGLIST latest"; fi
```

Assuming `$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH` is set to `master` if you use a separate branch `mybranch` the code above won't get executed so it's likely that the Kaniko command line doesn't have any a neither a valid `$FORMATTEDTAGLIST` or `$IMAGE_LABELS`.

You can debug by seeing their output on the script which is happening at the end before calling Kaniko:

```sh
...
echo $FORMATTEDTAGLIST
echo $IMAGE_LABELS
mkdir -p /kaniko/.docker
...
```

A hack would be to override `$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH` with your custom branch.

✌️

Comment: Thank You. This helped me out in a pinch.